# Get decimal number regular expression

Tags: java

I am trying to create a simple program to practice parsing data.  I'll show you my code then explain what I'm trying to do:

```
String data = "<span id=\"yfs_l84_ibm\">176.85</span>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+([.]\\d{2})?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
if (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

All I'm trying to do is print out "176.85."  There will always be two numbers after the decimal place, and 1 or more numbers in front of the decimal.  I don't need to worry about negative numbers, although it wouldn't hurt if my regular expression handled that.  My code gets inside the `if`, but prints `null`.  Is something wrong with my regular expression?  Below are other regular expressions I have tried.  They also print `null`, or never get inside the `if`.

1. ^[+-]?(\d+(.?\d+)?|.\d+)$
2. /^\d+.?\d*$/
3. /\d+.?\d*/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umm, try to change the pattern into this `\\d+\\.\\d{2}`
And `matcher.group(0)`
I've tried it and it worked well :)

Comment: Keep in mind that this regex will match numbers with more than 4 digits before the decimal point. :)

Comment: yes it will mr Pat :) , I'm sure that the numbers will go higher than 1000, so I give no limitation, but only 2 digits after the comma.

Comment: @A-SM Will this work if there is a comma before the decimal (i.e. 15,570.28)

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out: `\\d+\\,?\\d+\\.\\d{2}`

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to match numbers with the +/- as a prefix, use:

```
[-+]?\\d{1,4}\\.\\d{2}
```

And extract group 0.

Answer (score 0):

for its expression function:

```
(\\d+([.]\\d{2})?)
```